# Prisma - select where number contains a string

Tags: javascript, prisma

Given that model:

```
model User {
  id        Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  name      String
}
```

I have a variable `searchValue` and I would like to find all the users whose id (number) **contains** the search value. For example: if the searchValue is 10, users with id 10, 101, 1020, etc will be returned from the db.

Or, in simpler words, I would like to do that, but with numbers:

```
const res = await this.prisma.user.findMany({
   where: {
      { id: { contains: searchValue }}
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Prisma support custom filter like this, but you can just use native JS for the filtering I suppose.

```
prisma.user.findMany().filter(user => String(user.id).includes(searchValue))
```

Comment: This could work when there are few records in the database. With lots of database records one would want the filtering to happen in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Is this still not possible?
Would be much faster to do this in the DB instead of in JS.

Also the new [fulltext search feature](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/full-text-search) seems only to be possible for string fields.
But I have an autoincrement ID INT field and there is a searchfield where the user can search for IDs

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).